# Open an Angular 2 application in a new tab with post parameters and capture the post params using Angular2

Tags: angular

I have a requirement where my Angular2 application will be opened from a website in a new tab with post parameters. How can I capture the post parameters in angular 2?

Can we capture post parameters using Angular 2?

Comment: can you please ellaborate ?

Answer (score 1):

> In MarkUp:

```
<a target="_blank" routerLink="/parent-page/1/edit">  
// route should be parent-page/id/edit
```

> In Targeted Component:

```
import {ActivatedRoute, Params} from '@angular/router';

export class Component{
id
constructor( private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.subscription = this.route.params
        .subscribe(
            (params: Params) => {
                this.id = +params.id;
            }
        );
}
}
```